# Resolve namespaces in XDocument c#

Tags: c#, namespaces, linq-to-xml

I am importing some data from an XML file which contains a couple of namespaces. I am using nested classes to import data in different level. Unfortunately I cannot access the data in inner classes. I know the problem is regarding namespaces but I do not know how I can resolve them without modifying inner classes. Does anybody know how I can resolve namespaces in XDocument.

This is a part of that XML:

```
<TransXChange xmlns="http://www.transxchange.org.uk/" 
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
xmlns:apd="http://www.govtalk.gov.uk/people/AddressAndPersonalDetails" 
xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.transxchange.org.uk/ http://www.transxchange.org.uk/schema/2.1/TransXChange_registration.xsd" 
xml:lang="en" CreationDateTime="2004-06-09T14:20:00-05:00" 
>
    <Operators>
        <LicensedOperator id="O1" >
            <NationalOperatorCode>ABC</NationalOperatorCode>
            <OperatorAddresses>
                <CorrespondenceAddress>
                    <apd:Line>45 City Road</apd:Line>
                </CorrespondenceAddress>
            </OperatorAddresses>
        </LicensedOperator>
    </Operators>
</TransXChange>
```

Comment: a simple search here on SO should have shown you the solution

Answer (score 2):

You have to use the namespace that matches the one used in your XML, with Linq to XML you can use `XNamespace` for that i.e.:

```
XDocument doc = XDocument.Load("test.xml");
XNamespace apd = "http://www.govtalk.gov.uk/people/AddressAndPersonalDetails";
var firstHit = doc.Descendants(apd + "Line").First();
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to tell the parser how to reference the namespace:

```
XmlNamespaceManager nsmgr = new XmlNamespaceManager(xmlElem.OwnerDocument.NameTable);
nsmgr.AddNamespace("apd", "http://[PATH_TO_NAMESPACE_DOC]");
```

That should do it

Comment: I wonder if is there any way to resolve name spaces in XDocumet:XDocument doc = new XDocument();
            doc = XDocument.Load(filename);

Comment: Not that I know of. Is there a problem using `XmlNamespaceManager`?

Comment: Unfortunately I have got more than 40 classes and in all of them I used XDocument, xml linq, not XML Document